# Not able to find out if a radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is my code:

```
<input type="radio" id="allIB"style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this.id)">

<input type="radio" id="allOB" style="vertical-align:middle;height:10px;width:15px;top:10px;" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this.id)">

function enableSave1(id)
{
 abc=id;
 if(document.getElementById('abc').checked)
 {
  alert('done');
 }
}
```

This is not working properly and throwing an error (object required ...).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes (') around "abc" in getElementById

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the id parameter directly to the getElementById() function or without using getElementById:

```
<input type="radio" id="allIB" name="selMethodCode" value="" onClick="selInterface(this);enableSave1(this)">

function selInterface(radio){
if(radio.checked){
alert("done"+radio.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function enableSave1(id)
{
 if(document.getElementById(id).checked)
 {
  alert('done');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

`if(document.getElementById('abc').checked)` to `if(document.getElementById(abc).checked)`

Answer (score 0):

```
abc=id;
```

Here you declare a variable abc whose value is the same as the id parameter.

```
if(document.getElementById('abc').checked)
```

Here you look for the DOM node whose id is 'abc', not the value of the abc variable.

Answer (score 0):

Wat you are doing is asking `getelementbyid('abc')` to look for an element in your page with the id 'abc'. Instead, you want to reference your abc variable so you need to remove the quotes in your getelementbyid section

`getElementById(abc);`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name in `document.getElementById('abc').checked` can't have `''`. So, change your function to this:

```
function enableSave1(id)
{
 abc=id;
 if(document.getElementById(abc).checked)
 {
  alert('done');
 }
}
```

Also, you should change the `onClick` to `selInterface(this.id);enableSave1(this.id);`

Answer (score 0):

if(document.getElementById(id).checked)

will be like this.. previously it was searching for an element with id=='abc'. u can use the passed params directly in the code. why u need to assign it to a variable?